# SSH into Ubuntu over internet won't accept correct password

Tags: networking, server, ssh, password

This has been troubling me for the longest time.

I have Ubuntu 16.04 running on a laptop, and I can SSH into it fine from my Windows desktop. However, when I use my Pi, or anything else, to SSH into my laptop over the internet, it prompts me for my password, which I enter (correctly), but it says `Permission denied (publickey, password).`. Any ideas?

Comment: check if the user you are trying to connect to is the correct user. If you don't specify the user, then ssh asumes you want to connect to the same user as you are currently loged in as.

Comment: Connecting with enabled debugging may provide more hints, e. g. `ssh -v ...` (add more `-v` if required). On the server side you can look at `/var/log/auth.log` or you can run the SSH server in debug mode with `sudo sshd -d` (disable the SSH service first and add more `-d` if required).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to anyone who replied!

I had a quick brainwave, and tried something else:

I went on to my outermost router (our CentryLink modem) and changed the SSH port to 22222, then went to the other router (Netgear AP) and set the external port to 22222. What was probably happening was that the Pi was trying to SSH into the modem, rather than the server.

Having done that, everything works!